Возможно ли отключить физику прикосновений не отключая гравитацию в unity 2d
Есть враг перемещающийся рывками
    private void AddForce()
    {
        _rb.AddForce(-transform.right * _speed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

Игрок может его толкать, возможно ли это как-то исправить? Увеличивать трение не вариант, тогда враг не будет перемещаться. Лучшее что я придумал - уменьшить вес игрока, но мне кажется это может сказаться на геймплее

¿Игра случаем не платформер, навроде супер марио? Если так, то незачем было использовать физический движок.

Если на тело не должны воздействовать никакие силы, то оно должно быть кинетическим. Да, сила гравитации тоже не будет воздействовать на это тело, его прописывают вручную в FixedUpdate. Можно посмотреть, как это делают в демонстрационном проекте ThirdPerson c CharacterController, в 2d с кинетическим RigidBody всё тоже самое, но в двух осях.

Если тебе нужно, чтобы они сталкивались, но при этом он его не двигал, то да - поиграй с весами, как игрока, так и противника.
Если же тебе не нужно, чтобы они в принципе сталкивались, то можешь разнести их по разным слоям.

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
